# Scanner interfering with another

Tags: java

So I am trying to make a code that will prompt the user to either use a basic calculator, or a word counter that displays how many words are in a given sentence entered by the user, this is done using methods. I have figured out how to properly set up the calculator, but the word counter is giving me some issues:

```
    public static int wordCounter(String str){

      String words[]=str.split(" ");
       int count=words.length;
        return count;
  }



public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("What do you want to do( calculator(0)/word counter(1) )? ");  
   //This runs and I select '1' for word counter
   int choice = input.nextInt();    //Input the choice here

   if (choice == 0) {     
   // It runs this selection statment, and since zero is not selected, 
   //it runs the word Counter branch
      calculator();
  }else{
     System.out.println("Please enter a sentence:");     // Tells me to enter a sentence
     String sentence=input.nextLine();  
    //^ This input is completely skipped and goes 
    //right to the 'System.out.print(); Statement.

    System.out.print("There are "+ wordCounter(sentence) + " words in the sentence.");     
    //^ This prints a 1 immediately after the branch is selected with '1'
}

}
```

I'm not sure where it is going wrong since this only happens while it is in the  if/else statement. Doing some testing also showed me that it seems that the first scanner "int choice=input.nextInt()" Is somehow interfering with the second scanner for the string. Any ideas keeping a similar formatting would be greatly appreciated.

Please forgive my formatting, it may not look great.

Comment: where is the ***calculator*** method???

Comment: I didn't include it because that specific part works and was not the issue. I can include it if you would like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you enter the number `int choice = input.nextInt()` it's only scanning the integer, not the newline. So when you call `input.nextLine()` it instantly returns an empty string. One way to fix this would be to replace that line with

```
int choice = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much! Will mark this as solved once it lets me!

Answer (score 1):

`nextLine()` will only return the remainder of the current line being scanned.  Since you would have pressed enter after selecting the number, all it will capture is an empty string.

To fix it, just add a `nextLine()` directly after you get the integer.

> `public String nextLine()`
>
> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.
> Since this method continues to search through the input looking for a line separator, it may buffer all of the input searching for the line to skip if no line separators are present.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()